# Selenium Python (Import Error) Python-Selenium-Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, selenium, testing, automation

**After Running the below Command:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

**I get the Following error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tempjatop\workspace\TestPython\Sample.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.0b2-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .safari.webdriver import WebDriver as Safari  # noqa
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.0b2-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\safari\webdriver.py", line 49
    executable_path = os.environ.get("SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR")
                                                          ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

---

I don't know why it is redirecting it to safari webdriver.
Please suggest any fixes or am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says:

> TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Check for indentations in your code and correct the inconsistent ones.

Comment: for this command only - from selenium import webdriver,
There are no indentation errors :)
I think its the WebDriver that is causing the problem.